# how to setup 4 drives on hetzner servers, every two are mirror

Tags: raid, fdisk, hetzner, server-setup

I've a new dedicated server from hetzner, will install cPanel on it.

- 2x HDD SATA 6,0 TB Enterprise
- 2x SSD M.2 NVMe 512 GB
- OS is AlmaLinux v8.7.0

how can I set up the installimage so the OS be on the NVMe, and the cPanel home directory on the SATA?

installimage:

PART swap swap 32G

PART /boot ext3 1024M

PART / ext4 all

disks:

- Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512 GB (=> 476 GiB)
- Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 512 GB (=> 476 GiB)
- Disk /dev/sda: 6001 GB (=> 5589 GiB)
- Disk /dev/sdb: 6001 GB (=> 5589 GiB)

Total capacity 11 TiB with 4 Disks

I want the OS on NVMe with RAID1 between them,
home dir on HDD also RAID between them.

my guess solution in case no way to reach this directly from the installimage:

1. unmount the 6TB drives
2. setup normally with the NVMe and the RAID1 is created by default
3. install cpanel
4. mount the 6TB drives and fdisk and format them, and create RAID1 between them
5. change the home to the 6TB drive

any help in reaching this please?

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted? I need to do the same, except I have two 4 Tb HDDs. Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately no solution yet